# SQL ALTER attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Get the movie title for all movies that are comedy or horror, rename the output attribute name to be “Happily Scared”

```
SELECT comedy,horror 
FROM movie 
ALTER TABLE comedy,horror RENAME TO Happily Scared
```

I keep getting an error in the sql query. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: are you trying to `UPDATE` your data?  You need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to guess that you want to `UPDATE` your table. Without seeing your table structure you will want something like this:

```
update movie
set title = 'Happily Scared'
where genre in ('comedy', 'horror')
```

Update Syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: i get this error after i execute it >[Error] Script lines: 1-3 --------------------------
 ORA-00904: "GENRE": invalid identifier
 Script line 3, statement line 3, column 7

Comment: @ckp25 you need to update the query with the your table name and columns.